# The universal cover of BG

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Some good bibliography where is the construction of the classifying space $BG$ of a group $G$ (discrete) ... and also the construction of the universal cover $EG$ of $BG$?

Comment: Hatcher's Algebraic Topology section 1.B has a construction (BG as a quotient of the universal cover EG) and proves $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X),G)\cong[X,K(G,1)]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May's "Simplicial objects in Algbebraic Topology" S. V, pg. 93, constructs Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces using the simplicial bar construction. There is also May's "Classifying Spaces and Fibrations". All this is reviewed in a more elementary manner in "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" S. 16.5, pg. 128.

Tammo Tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology. S. 14.4, pg. 344 has an updated review of Milnor's construction. Another viewpoint is Dale Husemoller's "Fibre Bundles" S. 4.11, pg 54. Also "Cohomology of Finite Groups" by Adem-Milgram.

Some original articles include:

Milgram's paper "The Bar Construction and Abelian H-Spaces", which was later reviewed by Steenrod in "Milgram's Classifying Space of a Topological Group" and later again by Piccinini and Spreafico in "Milgram-Steenrod Construction of Classifying Spaces for Topological Groups".

Segal's approach in "Classifying Spaces and Spectral Sequences".

Milnor's "Construction of Universal Bundles I, II".

More genreally there is the construction of the projective planes of an H-space in: Stacheff "Homotopy Associativity of H-Spaces I, II", Sugawara "A Condition that a Space is Group-Like", "On a Condition That a Space is an H-Space", Dold-Lashof "Principal Quasifibrations and Fibre Homotopy Equivalences of Bundles".